# Reset Minecraft Registration

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, technical-issues

I have exceeded my account registration, (which is one), and I want to reset all of my Minecraft settings - I want everything deleted except Minecraft itself because I still want to play on servers.

So I need to know how to wipe out Minecraft out or delete previous account registrations.

Comment: Delete the .minecraft folder. when you re-run the launcher (Minecraft.exe) it'll run and re-download everything like it did when you first got it (so no worlds, versions and profiles except your own)

Comment: and how do you do that? @Memor-X

Comment: Open up Minecraft.exe, go to edit Profile then click on the button on the bottom right that days "Open Gamer Dir". in the Explorer Window click on the address bar and delete everything from the end starting with `.minecraft` so it should have `AppData\Roaming` at the end. you should then see the .minecraft folder, delete that then re-run Minecraft.exe, it should ask you to log in so it can then download all the files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exceeded my account registration"? I can't make any sense of that.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, so maybe I should have flagged it as unclear instead, but the answers to this question are answering an identical question to the duplicate.

Comment: It's quite clear, as I see it: both users want to have a completely fresh installation of Minecraft. The suggested duplicate seems valid.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are runnning Windows, just type `%appdata%` in your start menu, or your search bar in Windows 8. There, delete the `.minecraft` folder.